# Chrome issue animating one SVG across another with CSS transform

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to animate one SVG image across the screen over another SVG image, using CSS animations. I'm *really* close to getting it working like I want, but for some odd reason it's being weird in Chrome. Instead of moving 100% across the screen like in FF or Safari, it moves (slowly) to about 25% across the screen. What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/byk397ao/2/

```css
#container {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.svg-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
@keyframes truck-drive {
 0% {transform: translateX(0); }
 25% {transform: translateX(25%); }
 75% {transform: translateX(75%); }
 100% {transform: translateX(100%);}
}
.truck-drive {animation: truck-drive 5s linear 1;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg class="svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1200 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 150;" xml:space="preserve">
 <style type="text/css">
  .st0{fill:#6D6D6D;}
  .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
  .st2{fill:none;}
  .st3{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#231F20;}
 </style>
      <g id="road">
        <g>
          <rect x="0.5" y="86.5" class="st0" width="1199" height="27"/>
          <path d="M1199,87v26H1V87H1199 M1200,86H0v28h1200V86L1200,86z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
          <line class="st1" x1="-0.5" y1="99.5" x2="1199.5" y2="99.5"/>
          <g>
            <g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="-0.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="19.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="10.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="26.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="45.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="37" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="28.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="52.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="72.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="63.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="54.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="79.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="99.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="90.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="81.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="106.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="125.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="117" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="108.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="132.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="152.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="143.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="134.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="159.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="179.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="170.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="161.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="186.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="205.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="197" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="188.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="212.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="232.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="223.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="214.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="239.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="259.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="250.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="241.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="266.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="285.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="277" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="268.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="292.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="312.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="303.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="294.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="319.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="339.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="330.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="321.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="346.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="365.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="357" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="348.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="372.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="392.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="383.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="374.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="399.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="419.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="410.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="401.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="426.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="445.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="437" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="428.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="452.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="472.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="463.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="454.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="479.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="499.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="490.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="481.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="506.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="525.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="517" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="508.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="532.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="552.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="543.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="534.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="559.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="579.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="570.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="561.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="586.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="605.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="597" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="588.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="612.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="632.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="623.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="614.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="639.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="659.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="650.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="641.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="666.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="685.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="677" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="668.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="692.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="712.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="703.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="694.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="719.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="739.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="730.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="721.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="746.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="765.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="757" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="748.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="772.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="792.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="783.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="774.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="799.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="819.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="810.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="801.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="826.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="845.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="837" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="828.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="852.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="872.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="863.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="854.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="879.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="899.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="890.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="881.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="906.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="925.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="917" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="908.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="932.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="952.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="943.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="934.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="959.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="979.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="970.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="961.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="986.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1005.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="997" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="988.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1012.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1032.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1023.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1014.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1039.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1059.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1050.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1041.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1066.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1085.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1077" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1068.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1092.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1112.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1103.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1094.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1119.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1139.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1130.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1121.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1146.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1165.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1157" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1148.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1172.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1192.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1183.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1174.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <svg class="svg truck">
    <g class="truck-drive">
   <path d="M15,38h56.8v55.5H40.4l-0.1-4.3c0-3.3-1.1-6.2-3.4-8.6c-2.2-2.4-4.9-3.6-8.1-3.6c-3.2,0-5.9,1.2-8.1,3.6s-3.4,5.2-3.4,8.6
   v4.3H15V38z M22.1,82.6c1.9-2,4.1-2.9,6.7-2.9c2.6,0,4.9,1,6.7,2.9c1.9,2,2.8,4.3,2.8,7.1s-0.9,5.1-2.8,7.1c-1.9,2-4.1,2.9-6.7,2.9
   c-2.6,0-4.8-1-6.7-2.9c-1.9-2-2.8-4.3-2.8-7.1S20.2,84.6,22.1,82.6z M35.6,66.6v10.3h14.5V66.6h10.3V52.1H50.1V41.9H35.6v10.2H25.4
   v14.5H35.6z M59.1,30.5h4.4l1.4,6.3h-6.9L59.1,30.5z M73.6,47.7h9.9c1.8,0,3.1,0.8,3.8,2.5l5.1,12.4h2c3.5,0,5.3,1.4,5.3,4.1v26.7
   h-5.1v-4.3c0-3.3-1.1-6.2-3.4-8.6C89,78.2,86.3,77,83.1,77c-4.2,0-7.3,2-9.5,6.1V47.7z M76.4,82.6c1.9-2,4.1-2.9,6.7-2.9
   c2.6,0,4.9,1,6.7,2.9c1.9,2,2.8,4.3,2.8,7.1s-0.9,5.1-2.8,7.1c-1.9,2-4.1,2.9-6.7,2.9c-2.6,0-4.9-1-6.7-2.9c-1.9-2-2.8-4.3-2.8-7.1
   S74.5,84.6,76.4,82.6z M90.3,62.6l-4.7-12.2H75.3v12.2H90.3z"/>
    </g>
   </svg>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property `25vw`, `50vw`, etc for the keyframe values.
It appears the percentages are not realitive to the parent div.

The below works as expected in Chrome.
I will try to find a solution for using percentages as well.

Here is some [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) where you can find more about relative CSS Units.

```css
#container {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.svg-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
@keyframes truck-drive {
 0% {transform: translateX(0); }
 25% {transform: translateX(25vw); }
 75% {transform: translateX(75vw); }
 100% {transform: translateX(100vw);}
}
.truck-drive {animation: truck-drive 5s linear 1;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg class="svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1200 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 150;" xml:space="preserve">
 <style type="text/css">
  .st0{fill:#6D6D6D;}
  .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
  .st2{fill:none;}
  .st3{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#231F20;}
 </style>
      <g id="road">
        <g>
          <rect x="0.5" y="86.5" class="st0" width="1199" height="27"/>
          <path d="M1199,87v26H1V87H1199 M1200,86H0v28h1200V86L1200,86z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
          <line class="st1" x1="-0.5" y1="99.5" x2="1199.5" y2="99.5"/>
          <g>
            <g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="-0.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="19.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="10.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="26.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="45.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="37" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="28.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="52.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="72.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="63.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="54.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="79.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="99.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="90.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="81.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="106.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="125.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="117" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="108.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="132.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="152.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="143.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="134.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="159.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="179.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="170.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="161.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="186.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="205.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="197" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="188.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="212.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="232.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="223.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="214.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="239.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="259.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="250.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="241.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="266.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="285.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="277" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="268.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="292.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="312.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="303.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="294.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="319.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="339.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="330.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="321.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="346.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="365.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="357" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="348.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="372.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="392.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="383.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="374.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="399.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="419.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="410.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="401.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="426.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="445.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="437" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="428.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="452.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="472.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="463.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="454.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="479.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="499.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="490.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="481.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="506.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="525.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="517" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="508.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="532.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="552.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="543.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="534.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="559.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="579.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="570.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="561.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="586.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="605.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="597" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="588.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="612.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="632.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="623.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="614.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="639.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="659.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="650.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="641.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="666.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="685.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="677" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="668.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="692.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="712.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="703.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="694.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="719.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="739.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="730.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="721.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="746.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="765.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="757" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="748.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="772.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="792.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="783.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="774.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="799.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="819.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="810.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="801.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="826.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="845.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="837" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="828.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="852.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="872.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="863.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="854.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="879.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="899.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="890.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="881.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="906.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="925.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="917" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="908.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="932.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="952.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="943.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="934.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="959.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="979.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="970.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="961.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="986.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1005.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="997" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="988.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1012.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1032.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1023.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1014.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1039.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1059.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1050.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1041.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1066.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1085.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1077" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1068.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1092.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1112.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1103.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1094.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1119.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1139.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1130.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1121.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1146.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1165.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1157" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1148.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1172.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1192.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1183.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1174.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <svg class="svg truck">
    <g class="truck-drive">
   <path d="M15,38h56.8v55.5H40.4l-0.1-4.3c0-3.3-1.1-6.2-3.4-8.6c-2.2-2.4-4.9-3.6-8.1-3.6c-3.2,0-5.9,1.2-8.1,3.6s-3.4,5.2-3.4,8.6
   v4.3H15V38z M22.1,82.6c1.9-2,4.1-2.9,6.7-2.9c2.6,0,4.9,1,6.7,2.9c1.9,2,2.8,4.3,2.8,7.1s-0.9,5.1-2.8,7.1c-1.9,2-4.1,2.9-6.7,2.9
   c-2.6,0-4.8-1-6.7-2.9c-1.9-2-2.8-4.3-2.8-7.1S20.2,84.6,22.1,82.6z M35.6,66.6v10.3h14.5V66.6h10.3V52.1H50.1V41.9H35.6v10.2H25.4
   v14.5H35.6z M59.1,30.5h4.4l1.4,6.3h-6.9L59.1,30.5z M73.6,47.7h9.9c1.8,0,3.1,0.8,3.8,2.5l5.1,12.4h2c3.5,0,5.3,1.4,5.3,4.1v26.7
   h-5.1v-4.3c0-3.3-1.1-6.2-3.4-8.6C89,78.2,86.3,77,83.1,77c-4.2,0-7.3,2-9.5,6.1V47.7z M76.4,82.6c1.9-2,4.1-2.9,6.7-2.9
   c2.6,0,4.9,1,6.7,2.9c1.9,2,2.8,4.3,2.8,7.1s-0.9,5.1-2.8,7.1c-1.9,2-4.1,2.9-6.7,2.9c-2.6,0-4.9-1-6.7-2.9c-1.9-2-2.8-4.3-2.8-7.1
   S74.5,84.6,76.4,82.6z M90.3,62.6l-4.7-12.2H75.3v12.2H90.3z"/>
    </g>
   </svg>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohhh this is so close! Works great in FF and Chrome, but now the truck stops at 75/80% in Safari. I can probably make that work for my purposes but if you find a way to make percentages work I'd love to know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an unexpected way to get it working like I wanted. I set the max-width of the container to be the actual full-size width of my SVG, then set the translateX in px relative to the 1200px. It works in FF, Chrome and Safari even when the browser is smaller than 1200px. Would still love to know why the % units don't work as expected in Chrome though!

```css
#container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1200px;
}
.svg-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
@keyframes truck-drive {
 0% {transform: translateX(0); }
 100% {transform: translateX(1000px);}
}
.truck-drive {animation: truck-drive 2s linear 1 forwards;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg class="svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 1200 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 150;" xml:space="preserve">
 <style type="text/css">
  .st0{fill:#6D6D6D;}
  .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
  .st2{fill:none;}
  .st3{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#231F20;}
 </style>
      <g id="road">
        <g>
          <rect x="0.5" y="86.5" class="st0" width="1199" height="27"/>
          <path d="M1199,87v26H1V87H1199 M1200,86H0v28h1200V86L1200,86z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
          <line class="st1" x1="-0.5" y1="99.5" x2="1199.5" y2="99.5"/>
          <g>
            <g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="-0.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="19.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="10.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="26.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="45.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="37" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="28.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="52.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="72.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="63.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="54.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="79.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="99.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="90.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="81.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="106.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="125.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="117" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="108.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="132.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="152.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="143.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="134.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="159.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="179.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="170.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="161.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="186.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="205.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="197" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="188.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="212.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="232.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="223.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="214.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="239.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="259.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="250.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="241.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="266.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="285.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="277" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="268.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="292.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="312.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="303.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="294.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="319.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="339.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="330.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="321.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="346.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="365.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="357" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="348.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="372.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="392.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="383.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="374.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="399.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="419.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="410.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="401.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="426.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="445.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="437" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="428.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="452.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="472.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="463.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="454.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="479.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="499.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="490.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="481.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="506.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="525.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="517" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="508.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="532.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="552.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="543.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="534.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="559.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="579.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="570.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="561.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="586.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="605.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="597" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="588.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="612.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="632.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="623.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="614.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="639.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="659.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="650.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="641.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="666.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="685.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="677" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="668.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="692.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="712.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="703.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="694.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="719.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="739.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="730.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="721.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="746.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="765.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="757" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="748.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="772.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="792.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="783.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="774.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="799.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="819.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="810.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="801.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="826.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="845.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="837" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="828.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="852.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="872.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="863.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="854.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="879.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="899.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="890.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="881.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="906.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="925.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="917" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="908.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="932.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="952.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="943.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="934.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="959.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="979.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="970.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="961.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="986.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1005.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="997" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="988.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1012.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1032.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1023.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1014.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1039.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1059.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1050.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1041.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1066.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1085.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1077" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1068.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1092.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1112.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1103.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1094.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1119.5" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1139.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1130.4" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1121.5" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1146.2" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1165.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1157" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1148.2" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <rect x="1172.8" y="84.5" class="st2" width="26.7" height="30"/>
                  </g>
                  <rect x="1192.6" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1183.7" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                  <rect x="1174.9" y="98.4" class="st3" width="4.9" height="3"/>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <svg class="svg truck">
    <g class="truck-drive">
   <path d="M15,38h56.8v55.5H40.4l-0.1-4.3c0-3.3-1.1-6.2-3.4-8.6c-2.2-2.4-4.9-3.6-8.1-3.6c-3.2,0-5.9,1.2-8.1,3.6s-3.4,5.2-3.4,8.6
   v4.3H15V38z M22.1,82.6c1.9-2,4.1-2.9,6.7-2.9c2.6,0,4.9,1,6.7,2.9c1.9,2,2.8,4.3,2.8,7.1s-0.9,5.1-2.8,7.1c-1.9,2-4.1,2.9-6.7,2.9
   c-2.6,0-4.8-1-6.7-2.9c-1.9-2-2.8-4.3-2.8-7.1S20.2,84.6,22.1,82.6z M35.6,66.6v10.3h14.5V66.6h10.3V52.1H50.1V41.9H35.6v10.2H25.4
   v14.5H35.6z M59.1,30.5h4.4l1.4,6.3h-6.9L59.1,30.5z M73.6,47.7h9.9c1.8,0,3.1,0.8,3.8,2.5l5.1,12.4h2c3.5,0,5.3,1.4,5.3,4.1v26.7
   h-5.1v-4.3c0-3.3-1.1-6.2-3.4-8.6C89,78.2,86.3,77,83.1,77c-4.2,0-7.3,2-9.5,6.1V47.7z M76.4,82.6c1.9-2,4.1-2.9,6.7-2.9
   c2.6,0,4.9,1,6.7,2.9c1.9,2,2.8,4.3,2.8,7.1s-0.9,5.1-2.8,7.1c-1.9,2-4.1,2.9-6.7,2.9c-2.6,0-4.9-1-6.7-2.9c-1.9-2-2.8-4.3-2.8-7.1
   S74.5,84.6,76.4,82.6z M90.3,62.6l-4.7-12.2H75.3v12.2H90.3z"/>
    </g>
   </svg>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```